# geschlechtsneutrale Einzahlen von »Geschwister« und »Eltern«

Tags: gender, grammatical-number, gender-neutrality

Ich schreibe gerade eine Dokumentation für eine Software, die Hierarchien verarbeiten kann. Man kann sich unter einer Hierarchie das Verzeichnis-System auf einer Computerfestplatte, oder auch die Hierarchie innerhalb eines Heeres von Soldaten vorstellen.

Jedes Element der Hierarchie (»Knoten« in der Fachsprache) ist genau einem anderen Element untergeordnet, mit genau einer einzigen Ausnahme: Ganz oben in der Hierarchie steht ein einzelnes Element, das keinem anderen untergeordnet ist (Die Festplatte selbst bzw. der Staatschef).

Weil die graphische Darstellung aller hierarchischen Verknüpfungen an einen auf dem Kopf stehenden Baum erinnert, heißt eine solche Darstellung auch »Baum« (engl: »tree«), und das Element, das allein an der Spitze der Hierarchie steht, heißt demnach auch »Wurzel« (engl: »root«), und alle Knoten, die keine untergeordneten Elemente haben (Die Dateien im Dateisystem, bzw. die einfachen Rekruten in einer Armee) heißen, dieser Analogie folgend, »Blätter« (engl: »leaves«).
Damit endet aber die Baum-Analogie.

Hierarchien findet man aber auch in Verwandtschafts-Verhältnissen (unter der Voraussetzung, dass keine Inzucht-Verknüpfungen existieren). Daher stammen die englischen Bezeichnungen der Relationen zweier Knoten innerhalb desselben Baumes auch aus diesem Themenbereich.

### Kinder

Alle Elemente, die in der Hierarchie direkt unterhalb eines Elementes liegen, heißen auf Englisch »children«, ein einzelnes dieser Elemente ist ein »child«. Das kann man noch sehr einfach ins Deutsche übersetzen: »Kinder«, »Kind«.

### Eltern

Das eine Element in der Hierarchie, dass unmittelbar über einem Element liegt, heißt auf Englisch »Parent« (Singular und geschlechtsneutral). Beim Heer ist das der unmittelbare Vorgesetzte, beim Dateisystem jenes Verzeichnis, in dem sich die Datei oder das Unterverzeichnis befindet. In der Analogie der Verwandtschaften stammt aber jeder Mensch von zwei Eltern (Plural) ab. Die Singular-Eltern sind aber Vater (männlich) und Mutter (weiblich), also deutlich einem biologischen Geschlecht zuzuordnen.

Ich würde in meiner Software-Beschreibung aber gerne ein Wort verwenden, dass einen unmittelbaren Vorfahren unbestimmten biologischen Geschlechts beschreibt, so wie es das englische Wort »*parent*« tut. Ich habe gerade für den beschriebenen Fall bereits diese Begriffe gelesen:

- der Vater
- die Mutter
- der/das Elter

Die beiden ersten haben den Nachteil, dass sie mit einem biologischen Geschlecht behaftet sind, das dritte Wort scheint mir noch am passendsten. Ist es sinnvoll, dieses Wort für den beschriebenen Zweck zu verwenden? Ist es nicht zu unbekannt? Am häufigsten habe ich persönlich in diesem Zusammenhang nämlich »Mutter« gelesen, dicht gefolgt von »Vater«.

Alle Elemente auf der Linie, die vom betrachteten Element zur Wurzel führt (inklusive der Wurzel), heißen übrigens zusammengenommen »die Vorfahren« (engl: »ancestors«). Spricht man von einem bestimmten Element aus der Menge der Vorfahren, ohne dessen Abstand zum Ausgangselement zu thematisieren, dann spricht man von einem »Vorfahr« (»ancestor«). Die Bezeichnung »Vorfahr« für den Knoten, der auf english »parent« heißt, scheidet also aus, weil der Vorfahr auch ein Knoten aus der Großeltern oder Urgroßeltern-Hierarchieebene sein kann.

### Geschwister

Ein ähnliches Problem gibt es bei den Geschwister-Elementen, also den Kindern des *parent*-Knotens, die nicht mit dem betrachteten Knoten identisch sind. Das sind auf Englisch die »siblings«, also die »Geschwister«. Ein einzelnes Element aus dieser Menge ist auf Englisch ein »sibling«, was wieder ein geschlechtsneutrales Einzahl-Wort ist. Kann hier das Wort »das Geschwister« verwendet werden? Duden und Wiktionary bestätigen die Existenz dieser Einzahl-Form. Aber ist es angebracht, dieses Wort im beschriebenen Kontext auch zu verwenden?

Meiner Wahrnehmung nach wird am häufigsten das Wort »Bruder« verwendet (»Schwester« so gut wie gar nicht), und ich habe tatsächlich schon Abhandlungen gelesen, in denen die Begriffe »Mutter« und »Bruder« gemeinsam verwendet wurden, was dann zu Phrasen wie »der Bruder des Knotens X ist die Mutter von Knoten Y« führt. Und genau das will ich vermeiden. Ich will aber auch vermeiden, alle Knoten männlich oder alle weiblich zu machen.

Comment: Müssen die Begriffe einzeln stehen, oder können es auch Zusammensetzungen wie „Elternknoten“, „Geschwisterknoten“, „Kindknoten“ sein? Wenn einzeln, würde ich erwägen, ganz von dem Familienbild wegzugehen; es paßt ja ohnehin nicht besonders gut, mit jeweils nur einem Elternteil bzw. gar keinen Eltern an der Wurzel.

Comment: "Vorgänger" bezeichnet im Deutschen meistens nur den unmittelbaren "Vorfahr". Nachteil ist, dass eine Abgrenzung zwischen den Begriffen nicht direkt offensichtlich ist und diese schnell schon mal verwechselt oder gar gleich gesetzt werden können.

Comment: Also im Studium sprechen die Dozenten von: einem 'Elternknoten','Geschwisterknoten' und 'Kindknoten'. So wie von @chirlu erwähnt.

Comment: @chirlu: Die Verwandtschafts-Analogie möchte ich nicht verlassen, weil in der englischen Fachliteratur ausschließlich diese Analogie verwendet wird (abgesehen von »Baum, Wurzel, und Blatt«). »Der Elternknoten« und »der zweite Geschwisterknoten« sind zwar gute Alternativen, aber wenn man dann in einem vierzeiligen Absatz zum zwölften Mal »knoten« schreibt, kommt der Wunsch auf, darauf zu verzichten.

Comment: Vielleicht helfen Begriffe wie "Super-, Sub- und Nebenknoten", "Nachbar", "(direkter) Vorgänger/Nachfolger" weiter?

Comment: Auf wen ist die Dokumentation ausgerichtet? Ist es eine Fachdokumentation oder ein Benutzerhandbuch für Endanwender, die keinen IT-Technischen Hintergrund haben? Im Falle einer Fachdokumentation solltest du besser bei den englischen Fachbegriffen bleiben.

Comment: @userunknown: Die Verwandtschafts-Analogie möchte ich nicht verlassen, weil in der englischen Fachliteratur ausschließlich diese Analogie verwendet wird (abgesehen von »Baum, Wurzel, und Blatt«).

Comment: @try-catch-finally: Die Dokumentation ist für den Endanwender, von dem ich vorher nicht weis ob er von Hierarchie-Bäumen noch nie etwas gehört hat (und daher »der Elter« und »das Geschwister« nicht kennen wird), oder ob er ein Hierarchie-Baum-Fachmann ist (und daher die englischen Fachbegriffe bestens kennt).

Comment: @HubertSchölnast _das Elter_

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Zumindest bei Stackoverflow finde ich Fragen mit der Terminologie "Subnode", "Supernode", "Topnode", schon aber deutlich weniger als zu "childnode" et. al., auch bei Schreibung mit Blank ("sub node", "child node").

Comment: Eventuell statt Geschwister-Element den Begriff Nachbar-Element zu verwenden.  Hier wird zwar die Familienanalogie unterbrochen umgangssprachlich halte ich es für verständlich.

Comment: Ok hab grad gesehen, dass dieser Vorschlag schon gebracht wurde und nicht im sinne des Fragestellers ist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Die Baummetapher ist in der Informatik für gerichtete Graphen allgegenwärtig und wurde schon vorher in der Genealogie/Ahnenforschung für *Stammbäume* verwendet. Daher sind auch die Familienmetaphern naheliegend, u.a. spricht man auch von *Generationen* und *Verwandtschaft* sowie von *Zweigen* und *Verästelung*.

Die *Mutter* wird traditionell und nicht ganz grundlos eher und enger als der Vater mit der Fortpflanzung verbunden (*Muttersprache, Muttererde, Gebärmutter*). Man kann sich darüber streiten, ob damit das Geschlecht aller Knoten als weiblich bestimmt ist, man also auch wie im Wirtschaftsrecht üblich von *Töchtern* und *Schwestern* reden müsste, oder man zur ausgleichenden Gerechtigkeit männliche Begriffe wie *Söhne* oder *Brüder* verwenden sollte. 
Das Tripel *Elter*, *Kind* und *Geschwister* umgeht dieses Problem. Da in diesen Hierarchien ein Knoten meistens nicht aus der Verbindung zweier Elternknoten, sondern direkt aus einem Vorgängerknoten hervorgeht, finde ich das vielleicht ungewohnte, aber intuitiv verständliche Fachwort *Elter* völlig gerechtfertigt. *Elternteil* passt hingegen nicht, weil es eben immer nur einen Vorgänger gibt, der also gerade nicht Teil einer Paarbeziehung ist. *Geschwister* wird hingegen auch im Alltag im Singular verwendet, wenn das Geschlecht unbekannt oder unwichtig ist, und sollte daher unproblematisch sein.

Stattdessen kann man auch von *(direkten) Nach-* und *Vorfahren* oder *Nachfolgern* und *Vorgängern* sowie *(direkten) Nachbarn* auf derselben *Ebene* sprechen; dazu passt *Ursprung* statt *Wurzel*. Auch möglich sind graphisch-relationale Begriffe wie *Ober-/Über-, Unter-* und *Nebenknoten / -elemente*.

*Knoten* finde ich übrigens besser für ungerichtete Graphen, die eher *Netzen* gleichen und auch *Maschen* aufweisen. *Element* oder *Eintrag* wirkt allgemeiner.

Ein anderes passendes, aber ungebräuchliches Bild wäre das von *Quellen*, aus denen *Bäche* oder *Flüsse* entspringen, die dann als *Nebenläufe* ineinanderfließen und schließlich alle im *Meer / Ozean / See / Ziel* münden. Hierbei wären allerdings die Kanten wichtiger als die Knoten.

Answer (score 8):

Ich würde da ein bisschen tricksen und schlage Dir *Elternelement* und *Geschwisterelement* vor.

Das sind zwar Komposita, aber sie klingen weniger gewöhnungsbedürftig als "Elter" und "Geschwister (sgl.)", drücken im Vergleich dazu viel eindeutiger Geschlechtsneutralität und Singularität aus, und finden, basierend auf einer Google-Suche, bereits in technischen Dokumenten Verwendung. Zeitgleich ist *Element* ziemlich neutral bezüglich des Einsatzkontextes.

Comment: Wie ich in einem Kommentar zur Frage schon erwähnt habe, möchte ich nicht ständig von *Knoten* schreiben. Ständig von Elementen zu schreiben macht die Sache nicht wirklich besser (»Element« ist mit drei Silben sogar noch länger der als ein zweisilbiger »Knoten«)

Comment: @Hubert verstehe ich. Dann nimm's halt als Abwechslungsmöglichkeit dazu, so eine richtig ideale Lösung, die alle Bedingungen von Dir abdeckt, scheint es ja nicht zu geben bisher. Element finde ich semantisch viel viel neutraler als Knoten. Knoten passt einfach nicht in allen Kontexten, kommt ja auch primär aus der Graphentheorie.

Comment: Stimmt. Aber Bäume sind nichts weiter als Graphen mit besonderen Eigenschaften, daher kann man die Begriffe aus der Graphentheorie (also »Knoten« und »Kanten«) durchaus auch verwenden.

Answer (score 5):

Allgemein spricht man hier in der Informatik gerne von

> Elternknoten
>   Kindknoten
>   Blattknoten
>   Geschwisterknoten (Knoten, die dem selben Elternknoten zugeordnet sind, nicht jedoch alle Knoten auf einer Baum-Ebene)

Gerne auch von

> Übergeordneten Knoten
>   Untergeordneten Knoten
>   Nachgeordneten Knoten
>   Nebengeordneten Knoten (Alle Knoten einer Baumebene)

Answer (score 2):

Sowohl *Geschwister* (in der Einzahl) als auch *Elter* werden zwar als Fachsprachlich markiert, dürften aber, wie du erwähnst, von allen Muttersprachlern sofort verstanden und korrekt eingeordnet werden.

Ich sehe demnach absolut keine Probleme, solltest du diese Wörter verwenden.

In dem Zusammenhang: Als ich nur den Titel deiner Frage auf der Hauptseite gelesen habe, habe ich im Kopf schon eine Antwort formuliert, die geendet hätte mit: »Nimm doch ›Elter‹ und ›Geschwister‹.«

Comment: Nja, _Elter_ wird (im Kontext) sicher verstanden, aber zugleich als falsch bewertet werden.

Comment: @chirlu, also *ich* mag das Wort "Elter", seit es mir in der Schule im Biologieunterricht begegnet ist.

Comment: Ich find "Elter" auch schön, aber _geschrieben_ schrammt es halt immer knapp an "sieht wie Eiter aus" vorbei ;)

Answer (score 2):

#### Mutter - Tochter

Wenn in der Hierarchie eine Vererbung von zwei Partnern einer Ebene keine Rolle spielt, kann man durchaus auch auf eine eingeschlechtliche Formulierung (Mutter > Tochter) ausweichen, wie es z.B. in der Wirtschaft etabliert ist (*Mutterkonzern, Tochtergesellschaft*), aber das kann natürlich aus verschiedenen Gründen unerwünscht sein.

#### Elter - Elternteil

Wenn aus einer Ebene zwei (oder mehr) Partner zur Vererbung nötig sind, liegt der allgemein bekannte Begriff **Elternteil** nahe. In der Genetik kann man auch dann von [**Elter**](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elter) sprechen, wenn zur Vererbung nur ein Element vorhanden ist. Ich würde diesen Begriff aber nur in der Fachliteratur anwenden und in einem Laienartikel lieber zu Gunsten des bereits genannten **[Elternelements](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/26854/23)** darauf verzichten.

#### Geschwister

Hier ist eine Verwendung im Singular unproblematisch und wird auch außerhalb der Fachliteratur, wenn auch selten, gefunden. Hier setzt man aber mindestens 2 Verwandte derselben Ebene voraus.

---

Man sieht, dass Bilder aus dem Familienstammbaum problematisch sind. Das könnte man besser mit der *Mutter > Tochter > Schwester* Analogie lösen. Für Unix findet man neben Eltern- und Kindprozessen in der Literatur auch Mutter- und Tochterprozesse.

Comment: Und, um das zu ergänzen, scheinen besonders im Lehrbetrieb der Informatik immer wieder insbesondere Vaterknoten, aber auch Sohnknoten und Bruderknoten aufzutauchen.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: interessanterweise sind sie auch auf Italienisch männlich:  "un processo **figlio** è creato ... come un duplicato del processo **padre**" ;)

Comment: Meistens richtet sich das nach dem Genus des Grundworts (_der Vaterknoten_, _die Tochtergeschwulst_, _die Tochtergesellschaft_, _il processo padre_). Es spielt aber auch (im Deutschen) eine gewisse Abneigung gegen Zusammensetzungen mit _Sohn-_ hinein. Für Unternehmen hat sich die weibliche Form allgemein durchgesetzt, auch wenn es um _das Schwesterunternehmen_ oder _den Tochterbetrieb_ geht.

Answer (score 2):

Es gibt ja auch durchaus in der Informatik eine Tradition von deutschen Begriffen ...

In diesem Fall kann man nachschauen in *Algorithmen und Datenstrukturen* von Nicolaus Wirth (dem Erfinder der Programmiersprache Pascal). Dort ist dann im Kapitel über Bäume die Rede von **Knoten**, **Blättern**, einer **Wurzel**, **Vorgängern** und **Nachfolgern**, rechten und linken **Teilbäumen** und auch **Geschwistern**. Dagegen fehlen *Eltern*, *Kinder*, *Vater*, *Mutter*, *Tochter*, *Sohn*, *übergeordneter* oder *untergeordneter* Knoten usw. völlig.

Es geht also auch ohne wörtliche Übersetzung. Mir persönlich gefällt es so auch besser.

Comment: Die von Wirth eingeführten Begriffe machen ja auch keinerlei Probleme. Problematisch sind Begriffe aus der Gruppe, die du kursiv gesetzt hast, und auch diese Begriffe möchte ich nicht verzichten.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Der Punkt war, das es selbst in einem Fachbuch über Bäume als Datenstruktur auch völlig ohne diese Begriffe geht (man nehme z.B. Vorgänger für "parent", Nachfolger oder Teilbaum für "Children"). Man muss nicht alles wörtlich übersetzen.